# Editing a purely functional graph 

Tags: haskell, graph, editing, purely-functional

Let's say there is a graph and some set of functions like:

```
create-node :: Graph -> (Graph, Node)
split-node :: Graph -> Node -> (Graph, Node, Node)
```

I would like to create versions of those functions that don't expect `Graph` as an argument, mainly for convenience (preferably without monads so I wouldn't need to wrap every graph manipulating piece of code in a monad block). So what about this:

```
create-node :: (Graph -> (Graph, Node))
split-node :: (Graph -> Node) -> ((Graph -> Node), (Graph -> Node))
```

Or more generally:

```
fun :: (Graph -> Argument) -> ... -> (Graph -> Result)
```

I would then be able to use the `(Graph -> ...)` values as if they were normal nodes. In the end, to get a real graph out of a `(Graph -> ...)` value, just apply it to an empty graph. Is this a reasonable approach?

Comment: how are you storing your graphs?

Comment: @rampion: for the moment just a list of nodes and edges.

Comment: Your `create-node` function is identical; I'm rather wary of the `split-node` function, especially if you then call `split-node` again on each of the results... how do you ensure its the same graph, etc.?

Comment: @ivanm: look carefully - the former create-node returns a value, the latter - a value generating function; same goes for split-node.

Comment: @PhilipK the type signatures are identical, the fact that you put parens around it is purely for reading purposes.

Comment: @ivanm: indeed, Haskell's currying threw me off - I'm actually not writing this in Haskell, just using its syntax to describe type signatures. In any case - I meant to make the distinction between returning a value and returning a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so

```
create-node :: (Graph -> (Graph, Node))
```

*is* the state monad, just without the fancy newtype (and a flipped return value).  So I don't see the advantage of not using `State` here.  After all that lets me write fairly clean code using the state Monad:

```
 reverseEdgesM :: State Graph ()
 reverseEdgesM = do --...
```

Then pop out of it whenever I've got some pure code to run using `runState` and friends:

```
 reverseEdges :: Graph -> Graph
 reverseEdges = execState reverseEdgesM
```

If you do want to push forward with your functions idea, you may want to look into [difference lists](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Difference_list) to see how its done with simple lists.

Also, if you've just got some algorithms to implement, you may want to look into existing functional graph data structure libraries (like [fgl](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/fgl/5.4.2.4/doc/html/Data-Graph-Inductive-Graph.html)), rather than rolling your own.  If you want to understand the theory, check out [Erwig's paper on inductive graphs](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.28.9377).

Comment: Ah, thanks for reminding me about difference lists, will take another look at them; that paper also looks very interesting!